# C++ very weird behavior of double comparison

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, double

Simple double value comparison isn't working..
[image]

[image]

as seen in the screenshot,

```
double mag = 0.109981
double radius = 0.002
```

thus,

```
if(mag > radius) {
    // it's always false?
}
```

should be obviously true, but it isn't. How is 0.109981 not greater than 0.002?

What am I doing wrong here? It gives architecture warning, but I still don't understand what's going on here..

```
double mag = dVec.magnitude();
double radius = TOOL_TIP_RADIUS;
double diff = mag - radius;
cout << "mag: " << mag << endl << "radius: " << radius << endl << "diff: " << diff << endl << "mag > radius : " << (mag > radius) << endl;
if (mag > radius) {
    // no collision
    fve == (int) OUTSIDE;
}
```

Comment: You say the comparison isn't working but don't explain how you determined that it isn't working. You say it "should be obviously true, but it isn't" but don't say why you think it isn't.

Comment: The compiler optimized `fve == (int) OUTSIDE;` away since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does your program work, regardless of what you see in your debugger?  If so, then you are more than likely debugging an optimized build, where code has been moved around, eliminated, etc.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isn't 0.109981 always greater than 0.002? how's it not?

Comment: look at `mag > radius : 1`, you can clearly see that `mag` is greater (it would show 0 otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're assuming the line:

```
fve == (int) OUTSIDE;
```

does nothing because `fve` is not being set to `OUTSIDE`, it's because you're not *setting* `fve` to `OUTSIDE`.

You're comparing `fve` and `OUTSIDE` for equality then throwing away the result.

I suspect you *should* have written (with *one* `=`):

```
fve = (int) OUTSIDE;
```

Comment: Thanks! '==' was my typo, and that had been causing the code be optimized to skip that 'if' statement. Thanks alot!

Comment: always enable all warnings. The compiler will notify you on those cases